# How to optimise my app for android dark theme?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, darkmode

I am developing a quiz app and it works fine when light mode is on in my phone. But when i switch to dark mode, background color changes but the text remains black which makes it hard to read. How can I optimize my app so it works fine in dark mode also?

[image: My app in dark mode]

[image: App in light mode]

Comment: Hi @Sarthak, you can follow these to develop a better app for dark mode https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#support-dark-theme

Answer (score 1):

To summarise it in simple steps

1. Make sure your app theme is descendant of `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` or related theme like `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight`
2. Provide alternate colors for each color resource in the `colors.xml` file. So basically there will be two files `colors.xml` and `colors-night.xml` inside your `values/` directory. The one with the `night` qualifier will be applied when your devices switches to the dark theme
3. You can also provide custom attributes as colors in the `attrs.xml` but make sure to give values in each case i.e. night and day

The [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) explains it very simply

If you need to opt out of the global dark theme on Q and above, you can just use `Theme.AppCompat.Day` or Theme.MaterialComponents.Day` and other descendants

Answer (score 0):

Remove any properties `android:textColor` from your quiz question `TextView` and be sure to use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` in your `theme.xml` and `theme.xml (night)` files.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple, you just need to assign night mode colors in the `color.xml(night)` file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below code to change text view or other views color when the dark mode is on :

```
val isDarkMode = isDarkModeEnabled(this)
        if (isDarkMode) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dark)
            binding.TxtviwTitle.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE)

        } else {

            binding.TxtviwTitle.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK)

            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Light)
        }
```

here defined which text view's color should be changed on dark mode.